# how do i call a function and placing it into a method

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.SelectID').click(function (e) { 
var output;
        var select = $(this);
        switch (select.text()){
            case "FirstOption":
                var a = ("1");
                break;
            case "SecondOption":
                var b = ("2");
                break;
        }
        var output = [a|| b];
        return output;
    }
    $(document).on("click", "#Soemthinhg", function () {
    data1 = $('#something').val();
    data2 = $(output).val();

    AjaxMethod(data1, data2 )
});
});
```

> The question is that when I run the code it says 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'toLowerCase' of undefined or null reference

Answer (score 1):

You can use a closure scoped variable to do this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //declare it in a closure scope so that the global scope will not get polluted
    var output;
    $('.SelectID').click(function (e) {
        var select = $(this);
        switch (select.text()) {
            case "FirstOption":
                var a = ("1");
                break;
            case "SecondOption":
                var b = ("2");
                break;
        }
        output = [a || b];
    })
    $(document).on("click", "#Soemthinhg", function () {
        data1 = $('#something').val();
        //here use the closure variable
        data2 = $(output).val();

        AjaxMethod(data1, data2)
    });
});
```

---

Using global variable(not recommended)

```
//declare the variable in global scope
var output;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.SelectID').click(function (e) {
        var select = $(this);
        switch (select.text()) {
            case "FirstOption":
                var a = ("1");
                break;
            case "SecondOption":
                var b = ("2");
                break;
        }
        output = [a || b];
    })
});
$(document).on("click", "#Soemthinhg", function () {
    data1 = $('#something').val();
    //here use the global variable
    data2 = $(output).val();

    AjaxMethod(data1, data2)
});
```

Comment: This is the answer you are looking for. Declare output globally.

Comment: you have placed onclick #Soemthinhg function inside document ready function, what if i want that that function to be outside document ready?

Comment: @Dip in that case you need to declare the variable as a global variable not as a closure one... is there any specific reason to do so... in normal circumstances I'll not encourage adding variable to global scope..

Comment: There is no specific reason, i have used the above example as you recommended. But still my method cannot access the variable? i get an error of: 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'toLowerCase' of undefined or null reference. if i place a alert before  AjaxMethod so alert(data1, data2) its break point is not even hitting the alert? I think it means its not getting the data from the other function?

Comment: @Dip if the second event is called before the first one then the variable `output` will have the value as undfined

Comment: Ok. so onclick #something method i called just after document ready, i am getting a alert as undefined. I am not sure if this is another problem or i didnt understood you?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the output variable inside document.ready function, it wont be available outside the scope, If you want to access the output variable outside of the document.ready function, declare it as a global variable.

You can declare it as a global variable like `var output;` outside any function

or inside the document.ready function as `window.output = [a | b]`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.SelectID').click(function (e) { 
            var select = $(this);
            switch (select.text()){
                case "FirstOption":
                    var a = ("1");
                    break;
                case "SecondOption":
                    var b = ("2");
                    break;
            }
            window.output = [a|| b];
            return output;
        }
        });

    $(document).on("click", "#Soemthinhg", function () {
        data1 = $('#something').val();
        data2 = $(output).val();

        AjaxMethod(data1, data2 )
    });
```